Mad ex-movie-maker who makes his own movie monsters alive
I remember a TV series about a famous movie maker who got mad and in each episode he make a monster alive from his own old movie. There's a gang, like Scooby Doo gang, with two girls and two boys that tries to kill the monsters. One of them is a geek who make the gadgets from home appliances or garbage to kill the monsters. Some of the monsters are large spiders, crocodiles etc etc.
The non-geek guy gets help from a boy from the future who contacts him through the TV or computer and tells him that they will lose the ultimate fight and in the future monsters will rule the planet. The future boy is always in a hurry and leaves the middle of the conversations. The same guy also gets a newspaper article with a future date about the gang losing the fight. 
There was also some alien connection to the story, specially connected to the movie maker in some way. I think the movie maker met the aliens before getting mad. The movie maker also have a daughter who's also weird.
I saw the Hindi-dubbed version 4-5 years ago.

Finally after a long search I find out, its Monster Warriors about four teenage warriors fight with  B-Movie director who possesses the ability to bring his cinematic monsters to life. It run for two seasons.
From IMDb

The series follows the adventures of four teenagers fighting to
  safeguard Capital City from the vengeful wrath of insane and
  disgruntled B-Movie director, Klaus Von Steinhauer, who possesses the
  ability to bring his cinematic monsters to life. Over the course of
  the series, various story arcs occur that expand the series cast and
  city locations. Each week sees the teens customize common household
  objects into useful weapons to fight against monstrous creations.

